# Horizontal Layout messed up when using Jetpack Fragment Navigation

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, kotlin

Android dev beginner here. I've followed a tutorial for fragment-based navigation. I'm running into troubles when changing device orientation. It works fine on a real device, but in the emulator it is broker.

I've read some things about the view being re-rendered on device orientation change, but in my case the entire layout gets messed up, including the top bar as well as the bottom bar (back, etc.). A screenshot and code included below.

Note: layout looks completely fine when seeing it in design tab of XML layout file.

[image]

This is what it looks like in a vertical orientation:

[image]

Code for main activity and main fragment is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and my main fragment is this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainFragment"
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="30dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        ...some stuff here...

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This is a bit of a guess, but `ConstraintLayout` **does not support** `match_parent`. I see in your second code fragment that your child LinearLayout is using this; try changing it to `0dp` with constraints (like in your first fragment). I've seen `match_parent` cause really weird things like this before.

Comment: Don't think it's a problem with the application. I don't think the status bar gets rendered twice because of an application.  Do other applications work fine when you change orientation on the emulator??

Comment: @BenP. I tried using this, but no changes whatsoever.

Comment: @KyzerSoze you're right! Other apps get messed up, too! Maybe it's my emulator...

Comment: I tried deleting my emulator and running it on another one, but the same occurs! What should I try to do? @KyzerSoze

Comment: I cannot say what might be causing the issue. First, I suggest you check if you have the appropriate system requirements and then look into hardware acceleration. [Reference doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator#requirements). In the SDK Manager, install or update to the SDK tools, Android Emulator, Hypervisor Driver/ Emulator Accelerator (whichever is applicable)

Answer (score 1):

=> this looks incorrect:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

Try to follow this example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment android:name="com.example.news.ArticleListFragment"
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```